# How to chainload another kernel with kexec inside a LUKS2 + LVM2 partition?

Tags: boot, lvm, luks, dm-crypt, kexec

I have a Debian 11 installation with the following partition layout:

| path | format | mount point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/dev/nvme0n1p7` | `ext4` (no encryption) | `/boot` (Debian 11) |
| `/dev/nvme0n1p8` | `dm-crypt LUKS2` | `LVM2` (named `vg_main`) |
| `/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_swap` | `swap` | - |
| `/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_debian` | `ext4` | `/` (Debian 11) |
| `/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_ubuntu` | `ext4` | `/` (Ubuntu 22.04) |

The `/boot` for Ubuntu, lives inside its root file system (`/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_ubuntu`).
I'd like to kexec the Ubuntu kernel after booting the Debian kernel that lives in the unencrypted `/boot` partition that unlocks the `LUKS2` partition.

I'd like to use the [systemd kexec strategy described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kexec#Separate_/boot_partition).

Is there a way to pass any specific kernel parameter to Debian 11 (that I will do in a specially created `GRUB2` entry for this) to tell systemd to simple kexec the Ubuntu 22.04 kernel?

---

**Solution:**

Worked as per [@telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/704847#704888) suggestion, with just few adjustments:

/etc/systemd/system/ubuntu-kexec.target

```
[Unit]
Description=Ubuntu kexec target
Requires=sysinit.target ubuntu-kexec.service
After=sysinit.target ubuntu-kexec.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

/etc/systemd/system/ubuntu-kexec.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Ubuntu kexec service
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=sysinit.target
After=sysinit.target
Before=shutdown.target umount.target final.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mount -o defaults,ro /dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_ubuntu /mnt
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kexec -l /mnt/boot/vmlinuz --initrd=/mnt/boot/initrd.img --command-line="root=/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_ubuntu resume=UUID=[MY-UUID-HERE] ro quiet splash"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl kexec

[Install]
WantedBy=ubuntu-kexec.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to set up a `ubuntu-kexec.target` which would be essentially a stripped-down version of `multi-user.target`, with basically:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kexec an Ubuntu kernel from within an encrypted partition
Requires=basic.target    #You might get by with just sysinit.target here
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
Wants=ubuntu-kexec.service
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target ubuntu-kexec.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

This would invoke a `ubuntu-kexec.service`, which you would create to run your kexec command.

The kernel parameter would then be: `systemd.unit=ubuntu-kexec.target`, similar to how `rescue.target` or `emergency.target` can be invoked when necessary.

The idea is that `ubuntu-kexec.target` will pull in `basic.target` (or even just `sysinit.target`) to get the filesystems mounted, and then pull in the `ubuntu-kexec.service` which runs the actual `kexec` command line.

As far as I know, you can specify just one `systemd.unit=` option, and since you need to specify "boot as usual up to `sysinit.target`/`basic.target`, then pull in `ubuntu-kexec.service`, you'll need a unit of type `*.target` to specify all the necessary details.

Comment: It worked like a charm :-) I did just some adjustments as per your suggestions. As you mentioned, the `sysinit.target` was enough as requirement. Just updated the question with the final target and service files to eventually help others. Thanks a lot!